# Open/Save PDF using jQuery $.Get

Tags: jquery, pdf

Currently I am submitting a form to automatically open/save a PDF by executing following code

```
    HttpServletResponse response = request.getServletResponse(true);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf"); // Code 1
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
         " attachment; filename=\"name.pdf\"");
            Document document1 = new Document();
```

When I use jQuery $.get/$.post to execute above code, I do not get the pop-up option to open/save PDF, instead it looks like I get PDF in the firebug under response tab.

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
3 0 obj <</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 908>>stream
x��V�r�H}�+�*/ު5��7��Dw�Z��8aI  BI��w` �;�rI�s���鞆o�u�p ��<:�P�*���oo(Pɓs�Ɋ,=f�=�vi���_�%��J....
```

Is this possible with jQuery?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use jQuery's $.Get. Simply do

```
location.href = "TheURL"
```

Comment: Hi Amit, how do I know "TheURL"? If I handle with a submit form, I get pop-up automatically.., there I don't need any URL...

Comment: Are you doing a get or post? Either way, don't you have to pass the URL in jQuery call?

Comment: yes, I am passing the URL (tried both get and post without any success), this URL points to a servlet that executes the code I mentioned :  HttpServletResponse response = request.getServletResponse(true);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf"); // Code 1
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
         " attachment; filename=\"name.pdf\"");
            Document document1 = new Document();

Comment: Can you do the GET directly in browser? If so just use simple javascript to change the location to this URL and the browser would open the pdf. You don't need to use Ajax in this case.